# How to work with integrate 2 different array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with 2 different array which I want to integrate both of it become the result I want. But I have no idea how to do it.

This is my array which return current result for me :

```
foreach($getvote as $option){
        $data['id'] = $option['option_id'];
        $data['option'] = $option['option'];
    }
```

And the result is :

```
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) 
        [option] => Array ( [0] => this is option 1 for id 2 [1] => this is option 2 for id 2 ) )
```

But what I want is :

```
Array ([0]=>Array( [id] => 1 [option] => this is option 1 for id 2) 
       [1]=>Array( [id] => 2 [option]=> this is option 2 for id 2 ) )
```

This is `$getvote` result :

```
Array ([0] => Array ( [id] => 2 
       [option_id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) 
       [option] => Array ( [0] => this is option 1 for id 2 [1] => this is option 2 for id 2 ) 
       [subject] => test 2 
       [type] => 1 ) )
```

I don't know am I asking correct question. But I hope I can get some help from you all. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: try this... $i=0; foreach($getvote as $option){
        $data[$i]['id'] = $option['option_id'];
        $data[$i]['option'] = $option['option'];
$i++;    }

Comment: @kashan :  return same result what I tried.

Comment: please show your $getvote array print_r($getvote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 for($i =0; $i<count($getvote[0]['option_id']); $i++) {
     $data[$i]['id'] = $getvote[0]['option_id'][$i];
      $data[$i]['option'] = $getvote[0]['option'][$i];

  }
```

output :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [option] => this is option 1 for id 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [option] => this is option 2 for id 2
        )

)
```